# can't get php to run a .sh file containing a command to play a music file

Tags: php, sh, audio-player

I have written a php file that tries to run a .sh file in my system. Here is the code that i have written

```
system("/bin/sh /var/www/hello_world.sh");
```

the hello_world.sh has this command:
`cplay -r /home/saini/Music/music/Aadat.mp3`

i get following errors in apache error log :

```
[Thu Dec 22 11:43:18 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cplay", line 65, in <module>
    XTERM = re.search("rxvt|xterm", os.environ["TERM"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'TERM'
```

The .sh file runs successfully when I try to run it using terminal.

Comment: well, what is the shell script doing ? you might need to include the command for that

Comment: It looks like the `TERM` environment variable is not defined, and it is expected to be defined by "cplay".

Comment: This will help you : http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2009/08/14/readline-invisible-character-hack.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `exec()` or `passthru()` instead of `system()`?

Comment: use exec() function with your script